# Detox doesn't start iOS simulator on Circle CI

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, circleci, detox

When running detox UI tests on Circle CI, it gets stuck on starting up the simulator.

If I don't prestart simulator at all, tests get stuck on

```
detox info 5: Booting device DDB155A3...
```

If I try to prestart simulator with `xcrun instruments -w "iPad Air 2 (11.2)"`, prestarting fails with:

```
^D^DCoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Applications/Xcode-9.2.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsPackaging.framework/Versions/A/Resources/XRPackageModel.momd/XRPackageModel 9.0.omo'
instruments[700]: Waiting for device to boot...
Instruments Usage Error: No template (-t) specified
instruments, version 9.2 (63753)
usage: instruments [-t template] [-D document] [-l timeLimit] [-i #] [-w device] [[-p pid] | [application [-e variable value] [argument ...]]]
Exited with code 255
```

and tests get stuck on the same error as without prestarting.

If I try to prestart simulator with `xcrun simctl boot "iPad Air 2"` (which is recommended by this https://discuss.circleci.com/t/cant-find-simulator-xcode-9/16733), tests get stuck on:

```
detox info 1: Searching for device matching iPad Air 2...
```

Listing of simulators with `xcrun` shows there is iPad Air 2 (11.2) simulator.

Any ideas?

Circle CI 2

Detox 6.0.0

Release configuration

App is React Native app, platform iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We updated detox to 6.0.4 and it works now